# No confirmation upon job alert deletion...oops I didn't mean to

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

When managing job alerts, please provide a `confirm()` before allowing deletion.
This ensures that, yes, I really want to delete this record before simply deleting it.

[image]

Comment: Your hand drawn red circles look like an arrow, please edit.

Comment: Another way is like gmail, add an "undo" option right after deleting. This is less intrusive, and won't hinder those who really meant to delete.